# SQL Server : select based on another column specific search

Tags: sql-server

Hi Currently I am facing critical issue which out of my scope. Your help is highly appriciated.

Below is my table structure:

```
-----------------------------
num  name
1    Test
1    Test1
1    Test2
2    Test1
2    Test2
----------------------------
```

condition is actually name is my set : {'Test','Test1','Test2'}

If i am getting multiple records with diffrent name values I need to display only one record.

Condition : Test is the highest prioritym test1 is second and test2 is lowest priority.

from  the above table need to get only one record

```
1    Test   
1    Test1
1    Test2
------------
1  test
```

because in multiple records, Test is already there.

as well as from the remaing 2 records i need to get only 1 ; ie 2 test1 because test1 is the highest priority

```
2    Test1
2    Test2
```

Any body please help on this.

---

More clear sample and tried in this way
Sample data is like below . and I tried in below process, but not succeded.

```
GlobalID    SECURITY_TYP 
1        COMMON STOCK 
1        REIT     
1        Closed-End Fund 
2        Closed-End Fund 
3        REIT 
3        Closed-End Fund 
4        Closed-End Fund 
4        REIT
```

Priority order : { 'COMMON STOCK', 'REIT','Closed-End Fund'};

I need out put :

GlobalID    SECURITY_TYP

1            COMMON STOCK 
2            Closed-End Fund 
3           Closed-End Fund 
4           REIT

I tried in the below process.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
      SELECT temptest.*
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY globalid order by globalid ) AS RN 
      FROM temptest 
     ) AS t 
--where rn=1 
WHERE rn=1 

and output of the query is : 
GlobalID    SECURITY_TYP    RN 
1           COMMON STOCK    1           
2           Closed-End Fund 1 
3           REIT            1  
4           Closed-End Fund 1
```

but for global id 4 I need to get REIT ,( because it is the highest priority)

Comment: Provide an example of what you've tried already.  Your sample data is a little confusing.

Comment: How do you know the priority of test, test1, test2?

Comment: Priority is already fixed.

Comment: Sample data is like below . and  I tried in below process, but not succeded.GlobalID SECURITY_TYP
1 COMMON STOCK
1 REIT
1 Closed-End Fund
2 Closed-End Fund
3 REIT
3 Closed-End Fund
4 Closed-End Fund
4 REIT

Comment: I tried in the below process.
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT temptest.*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY globalid order by globalid ) AS RN
FROM temptest ) AS t
--where rn=1
WHERE rn=1 and output  of the query is :                                              GlobalID SECURITY_TYP RN
1 COMMON STOCK 1
2 Closed-End Fund 1
3 REIT         1
4 Closed-End Fund 1                                         but for global id 4 I need to get REIT ,( because it is the highest priority).

Comment: please add that to the question

Comment: sorry, this is first time i loged into the Stack over flow. where I have to add ?

Comment: @Daniel &  Michael  any body please look into this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a `#tmp`table and a `case` statement to create a Priority field to create the Rw number on. Or a CTE for that matter

Comment: @Daniel E., could you provide any sample for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT GlobalID
    ,SECURITY_TYP
    ,CASE  SECURITY_TYP
        WHEN 'COMMON STOCK' THEN 1
        WHEN 'REIT' THEN 2
        WHEN 'Closed-End Fund' THEN 3
        ELSE 999 --doesn't match
    END [Priority]
INTO #tmp
FROM temptest

SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT t.*
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY globalid order by Priority) AS RN 
  FROM #tmp t
 ) AS t1
WHERE rn=1
```

Untested, but try this. It assigns a priority and orders by that to get you only the highest priority available.

Comment: Thanks for your help , but it is not solved muy problem yet. It's assigning priority numbers, but we need to show only 4 records, less priority records should be ignored. I got some confidence because of you. some how alternate would be there.

Comment: I left out the Where RN =1 by mistake. Edited the answer.

Comment: :Seems it's good, and i will replicate the scenario. Thank you very much for  quick suuport.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? I added a column priority in the first result set - and from what you have described, this can be obtained easily depending on if it is common stock etc. When I am partitioning, I am ordering based on this value.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE
   (
    id Int IDENTITY(1, 1)
   ,num Int
   ,name Varchar(50)
   ,[priority] int
   )
INSERT   INTO @test
         SELECT   1
                 ,'Test'
                 ,1
INSERT   INTO @test
         SELECT   1
                 ,'Test1'
                 ,2
INSERT   INTO @test
         SELECT   1
                 ,'Test2'
                 ,1
INSERT   INTO @test
         SELECT   2
                 ,'Test1'
                 ,3
INSERT   INTO @test
         SELECT   2
                 ,'Test2'
                 ,2

select * from @test

SELECT   *
FROM     (
          SELECT  *
                 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY num ORDER BY priority) AS RN
          FROM    @test
         ) AS t 
where rn=1
```

Comment: No Sir, it's throwing errors.Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 19
Must declare the scalar variable "@counter".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 23
Must declare the scalar variable "@counter".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 25

Comment: and Priority is always fixed : {'Test','Test1', 'Test2'} means  if num  field value 1  and it may contains like exactly what you have created. then if name contains 'Test, it has to fetch only that record, remaining needs to be ignored

Comment: Did you copy all of the above script? If you are getting must declare counter - you missed a part. And yes it only gets the one - based on the priority.

Comment: :copied and declared the counter variable . but still below error occured.Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.

Comment: Edited answer - you are using a previous version of SQL Server while I am on 2012, that is why assigning default values to variables  was working on my end.

Comment: may be I am using sql server 2008 r2.SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT temptest.*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY num order by num ) AS RN
FROM temptest ) AS t
--where rn=1
WHERE rn=1
--ORDER BY num
select * from temptest  .. This query is giving half of the result , but I am unable to maintain priority here. Please help on this case